# How to set the size of google maps to not overlap BottomNavigationBar

Tags: google-maps, flutter, bottomnavigationview

I have the following code to set the size of the map overlay. Notice that the width is set based on a MediaQuery. The height was being set like this too, but it would always overlap the bottom navigation bar

```
void buildMap() async {
if (mapOverlayController != null) return;

var mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
// add delay so overlay is positioned correctly
await new Future<Null>.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 20));

mapOverlayController = GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(
  width: mq.size.width,
  height: 300.0,
  options: GoogleMapOptions(
    trackCameraPosition: true,
  ),
);
mapOverlayController.mapController.addListener(_onMapChanged);
mapOverlayController.overlayController.activateOverlay();
setState(() {});
 }

 Widget renderMap() {
if (mapOverlayController == null) {
  return Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 150.0,
              width: 150.0,
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.redAccent),
                value: null,
                strokeWidth: 7.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
                  "Loading.. please wait...",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]));
} else {
  return GoogleMapOverlay(controller: mapOverlayController);
}
}
```

I would like the height of the map to include all of the area below the map bar and above the bottom navigation bar

[image: I would like the height of the map to include all of the area below the map bar and above the bottom navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately those Google Map packages are not integrated in the widget tree of flutter and are just hanging on top of the flutter view as a native view.

Depending on your use case, if you just need an image of the map (with markers or an area on it) you can use the [Google static maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro), call their HTTP endpoint and get an image returned.

If you really need the adjustable map you would need to modify the native code itself depending on your needs.